# How bypass the lock and get html from site C#

Tags: c#

I need to get html from site. I do it usually using `WebClient.DownloadString(string)`. But in answer I get html html page like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">          
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center"><h3>Access is blocked by site administrator [27]</h3></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code:

```
var url = "http://site.ru";    
var client = new WebClient {Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")};
var resultHtml = client.DownloadString(url);
```

I try using `HttpClient().GetStringAsync(new Uri(url))`, but result the same.

Sorry for my english. And thanks for answers.

Comment: Are you able to open the site in your browser?

Comment: My IP is not blocked. I can open this site in browser.

Comment: Which site is it?

Comment: https://www.samsonopt.ru/

Comment: ok, checkout my answer for the User-Agent request header.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the site expects a `User-Agent` request header. So you can set it like this to trick the site into thinking that the request is coming from a browser:

```
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36";
```